# Carousel view for Android

Tags: android, 3d, carousel

I am working on a 3D carousel view for Android and I am running into various issues. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I tried Renderscript using [this carousel as an example](http://code.google.com/p/renderscript-examples/wiki/Carousel) but noticed some classes were now deprecated i.e. RenderScriptGL.SurfaceConfig. I searched but could not find any information on what to use instead.

Does anyone know and/or can point me to documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RenderScript as a graphic's component has been deprecated all together moving forward. So I would highly advise against using it. However, it is still being used as a compute language.

This looks like a pretty good open sourced library. I would start here.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-3D-Carousel

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I had seen the codeproject example before and made some changes to it but RS provided some cool effects :)